Confluent Kafka - Transaction Coordinator not running
My team and I are relatively new to Kafka and have had some success running kafka locally via a docker compose file and podman.
One of my colleagues created the compose file, configuring the config file based on https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html#confluent-kafka-configuration and the image reference listed here https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/image-reference.html.
When I try to use Kafka in a consumer - transform - producer scenario, for once only processing, I get errors. Specifically when calling InitTransaction (we're using the C# client) the logs in the terminal note that the Transaction Coordinator isn't running. I thought the transaction coordinator was a module that is part of the broker.
I'm curious to know if anyone has succeeded with Kafka locally using docker and has got transactional mechanisms working.
If so, I'd be grateful for any additional information that you could share on getting it working / getting the TransactionCoordinator running / working.
Edit:
I've moved on from my original position, to try to now use the confluent-local image. However, the issue that I now get is that the various services can't see the brokers.
The error I get now is:
broker           | Error while getting broker list.
broker           | java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes
schema-registry  | [2024-07-09 14:18:52,912] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (broker/{an-ip-address-here}:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
(sample is yaml, but wouldn't render nicely in code snippet, so dropped in under js code tooling).


---
services:

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/confluent-local:7.4.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:9092'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@broker:29093'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,CONTROLLER://broker:29093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'
      # Replace CLUSTER_ID with a unique base64 UUID using "bin/kafka-storage.sh random-uuid" 
      # See https://docs.confluent.io/kafka/operations-tools/kafka-tools.html#kafka-storage-sh
      CLUSTER_ID: 'MkU3OEVBNTcwNTJENDM2Qk'

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.6.1
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server-connect-base:7.6.1
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    command: >
        bash -c "
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir:latest
        && /etc/confluent/docker/run
        "
    volumes:
      - ./data/ISO20022:/mnt/ISO20022
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    #depends_on:
    #  - broker
    #  - schema-registry
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-7.6.1.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.6.1
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT-DEFAULT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_HEALTHCHECK_ENDPOINT: '/connectors'
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://localhost:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:7.5.0
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'




It should be part of the broker. Do the broker logs show any errors? Can you share your compose file?

I've edited the request. Change to a confluent local image, but now face an issue with the broker not being available.

I think that image makes some assumptions about connections, and cannot be modified like the others. Try this - https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/v7.6.1/cp-all-in-one-kraft/docker-compose.yml
